# How to make a "two dependent parameters" SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I just can't figure it out, what I mean by two dependents parameters is this :

Suppose I have records like these :

```
ID    Letter     Number
-----------------------
23    A          1
23    A          2
23    B          1
23    B          2
81    A          1
81    B          2
```

The user is to input this :

- First parameter : **A,B**
- Second parameter : **1,2**

Then only ID 23 would be returned, because it's the only one that respect all these conditions :

**A1, A2, B1, B2**

Every time I tried some query, 81 was returned...

In the context of my question it would be quick enough to make 4 conditions like  :

```
A and 1, A and 2, B and 1, B and 2
```

But imagine if i have 16 * 16 ...

It would be extremely long to write them all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `COUNT DISTINCT` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT Id
FROM #Tbl
WHERE
    Letter IN('A', 'B')
    AND Number IN(1, 2)
GROUP BY Id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT Letter) = 2
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT Number) = 2;
```

For more dynamic approach, you can put the criteria in table variables:

```
DECLARE @Letters TABLE(Letter CHAR(1));
DECLARE @Numbers TABLE(Number INT);

INSERT INTO @Letters VALUES ('A'), ('B');
INSERT INTO @Numbers VALUES (1), (2);

WITH CteCross(Letter, Number) AS(
    SELECT Letter, Number 
        FROM @Letters
        CROSS JOIN @Numbers
)
SELECT t.Id
FROM #Tbl t
INNER JOIN CteCross cc
    ON cc.Letter = t.Letter
    AND cc.Number = t.Number
GROUP BY t.Id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CteCross);
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/642479)</kbd>

Comment: See : `81 : a - 1`, `81 : b - 2` if you use distinct, the query consider that 81 has `a,1,b,2` but what should be return is only 23 because it has `a1,a2,b1,b2`

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Have you tried running the online demo? It only outputs 23.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier, the `HAVING` condition makes sure that all of the parameters were satisfied.

Comment: Just a little typo in your demo i think

Comment: @AntoinePelletier, Understood. See updated answer and demo.

Comment: Good logic with the cross table... but there is a problem with `WITH` in my SQL server... `incorrect syntax near CteCross, expecting (`

Comment: And the problem miraculously disappeared while I abused the execute button... Thanks a lot ! I really have to learn advanced SQL someday

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Glad to have been of help. Feel free to ask if you have any more problems.